# Get names of all numeric columns in a pandas DataFrame (filter by dtype)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dtype

Which `pandas` methods can be used to get names of the columns of a given `DataFrame` that have numeric `dtypes` (of all sizes, such as `uint8`, and not just 64-bit ones), using a single line of code? Note: in practice there are hundreds of columns, so `dtypes` (or another vectorized method) should be used for detecting data types.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[{"str_col": "some string",
                              "int_col": 0,
                              "float_col": 3.1415}])

test_df.dtypes[test_df.dtypes == np.dtype('float')].index.values[0]
# "float_col"

test_df.dtypes[test_df.dtypes == np.dtype('int')].index.values[0]
# "int_col"

# ?
# ["float_col", "int_col"]
```

Comment: numeric_cols = test_df.select_dtypes(include=['number']).columns.tolist()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the numerical columns:

```
numeric_cols = test_df.select_dtypes(include=['number']).columns.tolist()
```

Result:

```
['int_col', 'float_col']
```